# Zooming Google Map in WebView on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

I've created a WebView to display a Google Map with markers etc. This works pretty well and on my device (HTC Sensation) i can zoom the map in/out with no issus but on other devices it sometimes happens that zooming is not possibile. I already tried setSupportZoom(true) and setBuiltInZoomControls(true) but that doesn't work. Instead of zoom the map it just scales the content (like zooming in a picture).

So my questin is how can i enable zooming the map on all devices?